# Use do_mmap() in Linux device driver

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, linux-kernel, kernel

The device we work at now need to have a user space virtual memory address, we try to use do_mmap() as below:

```
*uvaddr = (void *)do_mmap(0, 0, size, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_ANONYMOUS, 0);
```

But we got following error

```
Unable to handle kernel paging request for data at ad8
```

Is it okay to use "do_mmap()" in a device driver? If not, any correct way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that `do_mmap` is succeeding, but `uvaddr` does not point to a valid location to store the result. To check this for sure, do something like:

```
void *mmap_result;
printk(KERN_DEBUG "uvaddr = %p", uvaddr);
mmap_result = (void *)do_mmap(0, 0, size, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_ANONYMOUS, 0);
printk(KERN_DEBUG "mmap_result = %p", mmap_result);
*uvaddr = mmap_result;
```

This should tell you for certain which is failing: the call to `do_mmap` or the assignment to `*uvaddr`.